# white spaces when selecting data from dropdown

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am creating a dropdown in angular js while selecting values some whitespaces are getting attached to dropdown values.

**Template**

```
<div class="row control-group">
    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 control-label">{{::'label.identity'|translate}}</label>

    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-9 col-lg-9 controls">
        <select id="selectIdentity" name="selectIdentity" required ng-trim="true" ng-change="changedValue(addUser.identityProvider)" ng-model="addUser.identityProvider" >
        <!-- Empty option necessary for placeholder to work -->
        <!-- <option value="">{{::'define.selectval'|translate}}</option> -->
        <option ng-repeat="idprovider in identityProvider"
                ui-select2="select2IdentityProvider"
                class="selectIdentity" 
                ng-selected="identityProvider"                  
                ui-select2="select2LocaleSettings">
            {{idprovider}}
        </option>                       
        </select> 
        <span class="help-block"
              ng-show="addUserForm.selectIdentity.$error.required">
              {{::'error.required'|translate}}
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS code**

```
$scope.identityProvider = ['Customer','Employee'];
```

Comment: ui-select2 is deprecated, you should try using ui-select : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

Comment: no still not working

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle or something to show what exactly is your problem?

Comment: i have two fields in dropdown employee and customer wen m selecting any of these options it is attaching so many blank spaces along with the value so when m matching the value in if else its getting failed

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :-

```
<select id="selectIdentity" name="selectIdentity" ng-model="addUser.identityProvider">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="value 1">{{'Value 1'}}</option>
    <option value="value 2">{{'Value 2}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: hey with this way its working, but we have to do this ng-repeat like if we have so many values

Comment: yes then do one thing, use `ng-repeat` in `<select>` and pass single parameter in value in `<option>` tag. I am little confused, if `ng-repeat` will not work on `<select> tag then try to use it in one `<option>` tag it will work on one of these.

Answer (score 0):

This code tested and there are no white space:

```
<select class="select2_single form-control" ng-model="module_id" tabindex="-1" ng-init="get_model_value()" id="module_id">
<option ng-repeat="item in moduleData" ng-selected="item.selected" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.module}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

this will hide the first white space in dropdown

```
<option value="" selected hidden />
```

this selected hidden will hide the white space

```
<select id="selectIdentity" name="selectIdentity" required ng-trim="true" ng-change="changedValue(addUser.identityProvider)" ng-model="addUser.identityProvider" >
       <option value="" selected hidden />
        <option ng-repeat="idprovider in identityProvider"
                ui-select2="select2IdentityProvider"
                class="selectIdentity" 
                ng-selected="identityProvider"                  
                ui-select2="select2LocaleSettings">
            {{idprovider}}
        </option>                       
        </select>
```